# Two numbers $a$ and $b$ are selected at random from $1,2,3\ldots100$ and are multiplied. The probability that the product $ab$ is divisible by $3$ is

Tags: probability

My approach:

In $1,2,3\ldots 100$ there are $33$ multiples of $3$.Therefore $1$ number is chosen from these $33$ numbers and from the remaining numbers ( except the one chosen) another number is chosen.

$$\frac{{33\choose 1}\cdot{99\choose 1}}{100\choose 2}$$

But my answer is wrong. Can you explain why?

The correct approach is

$$\frac{{33\choose 1}\cdot{67\choose 1}+{33\choose 2}}{100\choose 2}$$

Thank you

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Must the two numbers be distinct?  Assuming that to be the case, then the  probability that the first is not divisible by $3$ is $\frac {67}{100}$ and, given that, the probability that the second is not divisible by $3$ is $\frac {66}{99}$ so the answer is $1-\frac {67}{100}\times\frac {66}{99}$.

Comment: @lulu I thought that the probability of getting a multiple of $3$ is $33/100$ plus the probability that the second is a multiple of $3$ that is $33/99$. So I got $\frac{33}{100}+\frac{33}{99}$. Why is my answer wrong?

Comment: @Raffaele  Those events are not disjoint.  If you want to attack it directly, then there are two (or three, depending on how you count) ways to get a multiple of $3$.  Either $a$ is divisible by $3$ and $b$ isn't, or $a$ isn't but $b$ is, or both $a,b$ are.  Easier to attack from the other direction (as there is only one way the product might not be divisible by $3$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your calculation is that you have counted certain choices twice - precisely those choices where both numbers are divisible by $3$. If $a$ and $b$ are both divisible by $3$, you've counted that once as $a$ being one of "the $33$" and $b$ being one of "the $99$", and again as $b$ being one of "the $33$" and $a$ being one of "the $99$".

The correct number of pairs is therefore smaller by the number of those duplicates, i.e. ${33 \choose 2}$. And, indeed:

$$\frac{{33\choose 1}\cdot {99\choose 1}-{33\choose 2}}{100\choose 2}=\frac{2739}{4950}=\frac{{33\choose 1}\cdot{67\choose 1}+{33\choose 2}}{100\choose 2}$$

(as in the "correct approach" - however that approach is justified!).

In fact, as per @lulu's comment, it is a lot easier to calculate the probability $ab$ is *not* divisible by $3$, which is:

$$\frac{67\choose 2}{100\choose 2}=\frac{2211}{4950}$$

from which it follows that the probability you are after is $1-\frac{2211}{4950}=\frac{2739}{4950}$.